# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException setSpan (4 ... 4) Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (4 ... 4) ends beyond length 0
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1018)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:611)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:607)
   at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
   at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
   at android.widget.EditText.setSelection(EditText.java:99)
   at android.widget.EditText.performAccessibilityAction(EditText.java:145)
   at android.widget.NumberPicker$AccessibilityNodeProviderImpl.performAction(NumberPicker.java:2394)
   at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.perfromAccessibilityActionUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:619)
   at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$500(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:53)
   at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1149)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

My Android Studio App Not Open by some devices. They've got this exception. I don't understand why?
I Changed All Edittext to Textview but exception same

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException setSpan (4 ... 4) ends beyond length 0 android.widget.EditText.setSelection
```

Comment: Attach your code please

Comment: actually my code is a bit long i don't know which code line has the problem

Comment: Your issue is in spannablestringbuilder

Comment: It's device problem not your code ... looks like problem with some Accessibility service on the device

Comment: i see the exception on the firebase. Test are made by many devices and lots of them have the exception

Comment: Your edittexts are probably empty and you try to set selection ... it could not work

Comment: i remove editexts to textview but exception still same

Comment: i don't know SpannableStringBuilder. Probably it's automaticly created. But i opened it and many variables are red

Comment: i attached a class. I think the problems comes out there. May you check it? a bit long sry.

Comment: generally if sdk <= 23 problem occurs

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem too. :(